# Joomla Language not getting Converted even after Logging with a different Language option

Tags: php, csv, joomla

In my Plugin I have created a Language File for CSV Export

```
TRAVELINSURANCE_EXPORT_ORDER_ID="Order ID"
TRAVELINSURANCE_EXPORT_CUSTOMER_NAME="Customer Name"
TRAVELINSURANCE_EXPORT_CUSTOMER_EMAIL="Customer Email"
TRAVELINSURANCE_EXPORT_CUSTOMER_DOB="Customer DOB"
TRAVELINSURANCE_EXPORT_CUSTOMER_NOTE="Customer Note"
```

Those Language Keys are defined in my Export CSV Header

I login to my Joomla administrator using my Username & Password, Selecting Danish Language.

When I Download CSV it displays English Language in the Header instead of translating to Danish language. How to get header translated while downloading the CSV file. I am New to Joomla.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093858/how-to-roll-back-joomla-3-6-2-to-3-6-0

Answer (score 0):

There is good explanation of language files to be used in Joomla Extensions. You can get it here https://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files
For your case you can use this

For the back-end language files:

```
$language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR, 'da-DK', true);
```

For the front-end language files:

```
$language = JFactory::getLanguage();
$language->load('com_yourcomponentname', JPATH_SITE, 'da-DK', true);
```