# How to roll back Joomla 3.6.2 to 3.6.0

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

How to roll back  Joomla 3.6.2 to 3.6.0 for Overriding Language Core Files. I newly add a language key in language core file. When I select danish language to login and access language key is not translated into Danish language.

Comment: Uh, you mean downgrade?

Comment: It's downgrade not update.

Comment: yes i want Downgrade.

Comment: DO NOT downgrade. This is the worst possible solution you can do. You should not be editing core language files anyway

Comment: I Newly Added some Language Keys and Values in Pluging Language File. Newly added Keys Cannot Translated into Installed Languages. How can i do? @Lodder

Answer (score 0):

You can add different language keys and values using the built in language override function. Look in the backend under languages